# Bundling multiple smaller apps in a SPA application

Tags: single-page-application, aurelia, webpack-2, monorepo

Sorry for the long-winded question, but it's a complicated setup. Our application is a SPA in a Monorepo. The application is kind of a "shell" that loads smaller individual applications into it. Our folder structure is as follows:

```
Root/
  build/        - All our dev tools and config (including webpack)
  node_modules/ - All the dev dependencies for tooling are here
  projects/
    apps/
      shell/
      app1/
        node_modules/ - All the app dependencies and dev dependencies are here
        src/
        package.json
        tsconfig.json
      app2/
      ...etc
    components/
      comp1/
        src/
        package.json
        tsconfig.json
      comp2/
    core/
      bootstrapper/ 
        src/
          index.ts
        package.json
```

So in this structure, the "shell" application is the application that loads each of "app1", "app2" etc. That means in the shell app, there's a dependency on app1, app2, etc. But in addition to this, each of the individual apps can also be run standalone without needing to run from shell.

The components are components we wrote, and are dependencies of apps, or of other components.

The bootstrapper is what holds all the dependencies of framework code (in this case aurelia and redux). It is a devDependency of every app, but is a dependency of shell. This allows devs to run apps standalone when developing (but not in production, where it's always run from shell).

Currently, to get things to build and ship, webpack bundles everything in shell into a single file, and then deploys that. All is well, everything works, but this is not ideal.

Every app in this project is owned by different teams. Each team has their own release cycles, and we want to be able to allow them to build and deploy their own apps without impacting others. The ideal setup (after bundling) would be:

```
bootstrapper.hash.js // Contains our bootstrapper and framework code
app1.hash.js         // Contains the app and its dependencies (except bootstrapper and framework)
app2.hash.js         // etc
shell.hash.js        // The shell code
```

What we'd like from this, is to be able to load the shell app, and only load the app1/app2 js files as needed. From my understanding, we'd need to use a script loader to do this on-demand since webpack doesn't handle this use case, which I'm fine with. What I can't figure out though, is how to build each individual app without the bootstrapper code, and having it be able to be brought in dynamically at runtime.

We'd also want the apps to be locateable at runtime, without needing to redeploy other apps. If we add an app3.hash.js, we'd want to be able to load that dynamically.

What I can't figure out is how to bundle the apps the way we want. The closest I've gotten, is to use CommonsChunksPlugin, but this requires us to build shell. We'd ideally want something like how DllPlugin works, so we can build each app separately, but that requires a reference to it's manifest from shell, which requires us to build shell. We also tried combinations library and libraryTarget and externals, with no success.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at this https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-import/ ? Also add the webpack version please.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work for me since I need a fully-dynamic import. Static analysis doesn't work in my use case.

Comment: Hey, did you find an answer to this?